# c# error Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'HRDMSV1.User' is less accessible than method

Tags: c#, class, parameters

I am having a problem with an error...

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'HRDMSV1.User' is less accessible than method 'HRDMSV1.FrmAddDoc.FrmAddDoc(HRDMSV1.User)'

All help appreciated?

```cs
namespace HRDMSV1
{
  public partial class FrmAddDoc : Form
  {
    User _user;
    private ConnStr connStr = new ConnStr();

    public FrmAddDoc(User user)  /* error here */
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      _user = user;
    }
  /*...*/
  }

  class User
  {
    private String _userName;
    private String _password;
    private bool _readOnly;
    private int _userID;

    public String userName { 
      get { return _userName; }
      set { _userName = value; } 
    }
    public String password {
      get { return _password; }
      set { _password = value; }
    }
    public bool readOnly {
      get { return _readOnly; }
      set { _readOnly = value; }
    }
    public int userID {
      get { return _userID; }
      set { _userID = value; }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your  `User` class code?

Comment: You cannot use a class which is not public as a public method parameter, field or property.

Comment: I have added User class

Answer (score 1):

Your `User` class is less accesable than the `public` constructor `FrmAddDoc` which is not allowed. For more reference see [CS0051](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0051)

Comment: Hi,Thanks that worked, I made User class public, but I still dont know what the problem is tho?  Secondly is there any other way to pass an isntance of a class from one form to another, ?

Comment: The problem is that it is not allowed by the C# semantics and thus it is captured at compile time. Think about it for a moment how would you call the constructor since you cannot create an instance of the private `User` class? 
I'm not sure I understand your second question. If this problem is solved it would be best to mark an accepted answer and open a new thread with the new problem :)

Comment: A class without an accessibility level specified is [default private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels) so by *not* specifying `public class User...` you're getting `private class User ...`